# How to fetch paginated result for table in ManyToMany association

Tags: java, hibernate

I am having a User entity which is modeled as

```
@Entity
class User {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="user_roles",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(
            name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(
            name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")
        )
    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
}
```

I want to list this user specific roles in paginated view. for other classes I am using HibernateTemplate like this

```
public PagedBean<User> findUsers(inal Status status, final PageParameters pageParameters) {
    return (PagedBean<User>) hibernateTemplate.execute(new HibernateCallback(){
    public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        Criteria crit = getUserByStatusCriteria(status, session);
        crit.addOrder(Order.asc("id"));
        Criteria critWithoutOrder = getUserByStatusCriteria(status, session);
        PagedResultBean<RssFeedSource> pagedResultBean = new PagedBean<User>(pageParameters);
        return populateFromCriteria(crit, critWithoutOrder, pagedBean);
    }

    private Criteria getUserByStatusCriteria(final Status status, Session session) {
        Criteria c = session.createCriteria(User.class);
        c.add(Restrictions.eq("status", status));
        return c;
    }});
```

}

How to achieve this paginated result as the same way above for 'user_roles' which is not a entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hibernate:

```
Query q= session.createQuery("SELECT r FROM User u JOIN u.roles r WHERE u.id = :userId");
q.setString("userId", userId);
q.setMaxResults(10); // page size 10
q.setFirstResult(30); // page 4
List<?> roleList = q.list();
```

Comment: I am using Spring Framework, what would be the equivalent there. Do provide some pointers, since its not clear how to do this?

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect Hibernate's API.  roleList will be a List<Role>